# Vim: need help with a tiny script code to highlight

Tags: vim, scripting, highlight

I need a script code to highlight "[Capítulo" and "]" and everything between them. Thank you.

I want it to work everytime I open , for example, a .txt file. Just like code highlighting.

Comment: If you type /\[Capitulo.*\]/ what happens?

Comment: Also want it to script right?  Clarifiy that in the quesiton or else every answer will be the same!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an easy way to do it:

in vim,  make sure syntax highlighting is on with `:syn on`

run the command `:highlight` to get a listing of all the highlight group names, and samples of what they look like. The `Error` group looks like it stands out well in my colorscheme, so I'll use that in my example (but you can use any of the other names, like `Todo` or `Search`)

```
:syntax match Error /\[Capítulo[^\]]*\]/
```

This pattern will keep you from greedily matching the largest chunk.  Even though other people are suggesting you use the regular expression `/\[Capítulo.*\]/` - it's probably not what you want, because it will match everything in between if there are two or more such patterns on a line.

For example `/\[Capítulo.*\]/` will match this entire line:

> **[Capítulo foo] these words should not be highlighted [Capítulo bar]**

The same example but with `/\[Capítulo[^\]]*\]/` will only match stuff inside []:

> **[Capítulo foo]** these words should not be highlighted **[Capítulo bar]**

With regular expressions, it's a common trick to make a group  that matches everything but the character that you want to end your match, instead of using the `.*` which will match as many characters as it can. In this case, we make the group `[^\]]*` - which says "*match everything except ].*"

If this works the way you want it to, add the syntax match line without the "`:`" to your .vimrc

Comment: Another option for avoiding the closing bracket is to use a non-greedy match: /\[Capítulo.\{-}\]/.  \{-} is Vim's equivalent to Perl's *? operator and says match zero or more, as few as possible.

Answer (score 1):

A regular expression is what you're looking for:

Type `/` to enter in "search mode" and type:

```
\[Capítulo.*\]/
```

Comment: then you need to turn on highlighting :set hls